# Accessing multiple classes and ids in an ES6 array

Tags: javascript

How would I go about accessing a specific id or class that's inside querySelectorAll but in es6? I need to target specific elements for specific animations.

HTML

```
<div id="title">...</div>
<div class="text">...</div> 
<div id="image">...</div>
```

What I'd like to do something like this

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll("#title, .text, #image");
elemsArray = [...elems];

elemsArray.forEach(element => {
  elemsArray[0].classList.add("title-animation");
  elemsArray[1].classList.add("text-animation");
  elemsArray[2].classList.add("image-animation");
});
```

Instead of what I currently have

```
let titleAnim = document.querySelectorAll("#title"),
    textAnim = document.querySelectorAll(".text"),
    imageAnim = document.querySelectorAll("#image");

for (const title of titleAnim) {
    title.classList.add("title-animation");
}
for (const text of textAnim) {
    text.classList.add("text-animation");
}
for (const image of imageAnim) {
    image.classList.add("image-animation");
}
```

What is the ES6 equivalent to the code above? Also, here's the classic version

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#title, .text, #image");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
 elements[i, 0].classList.add("title-animation");
 elements[i, 1].classList.add("text-animation");
 elements[i, 2].classList.add("text-animation");
}
```

**Update:**

Here's what works thanks to  Darth

```
const elems = [...document.querySelectorAll("#title, .text, #image")];
elems.forEach(element => {
  let clas = "";
  if(element.id === "title") clas = "title-animation";
  if(element.id === "image") clas = "image-animation";
  if(element.classList.contains ("text")) clas = "text-animation";
  element.classList.add(clas)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const elems = [...document.querySelectorAll("#title, .text, #image")];

elems.forEach((element, i) => 
  element.classList.add(["title-animation", "text-animation","image-animation"][i%3]))
  
// code above will work only if elements are ordered.
// if not, you need to check each element for choose class:


elems.forEach(element => {
  let clas = "";
  if(element.id === "title") clas = "title-animation";
  if(element.id === "image") clas = "image-animation";
  if(element.classList.contains ("text")) clas = "text-animation";
  element.classList.add(clas)
});
```

```css
.title-animation{ color: green }
.text-animation{ color: red }
.image-animation{ color: blue }
div{ font-size: 50px; }
```

```html
<div id="title">...</div>
<div class="text">...</div> 
<div id="image">...</div>
```

No ifs:

```js
[
  ["#title", "title-animation"], 
  [".text", "text-animation"], 
  ["#image", "image-animation"]
].forEach(([selector, className]) => 
 [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]
   .forEach(el => el.classList.add(className))
)
```

```css
.title-animation{ color: green }
.text-animation{ color: red }
.image-animation{ color: blue }
div{ font-size: 50px; }
```

```html
<div id="title">...</div>
<div class="text">...</div> 
<div id="image">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. Quickly figured out that I need to repeat the list of if(ids/classes) 3 times, would sticking the multiple "if(element.id === "title") clas" parts in a function or an array be manageable, but still able to add the individual animations in some way?

Comment: @thx1138 You need to apply different classes to different collections. Its not best way to mix all collections and then trying to define each element back. I up the answer with no-ifs version

Comment: This is a much cleaner, flexible solution, thank you. With this one, classes can be mixed, added and have any number without breaking. This was the issue with the first solution, where everything had to be in order. But this is perfect.